# Clone of a div changing as the original div is being changed

Tags: jquery, css, clone

I have a div "maindiv". This further has divs inside it including "imagediv". In jQuery, I write :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ......

    var copydiv = $('#maindiv').clone();
    var number = 1;
    $("body").delegate("#imagediv", "mousedown", function(event) {

        $("#maindiv").attr('id', "changedmain" + number);
        $("#imagediv").attr('id', "changedimage" + number);
        copydiv.insertAfter("#appendafter");
        number = number + 1;
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="appendafter"></div>
<div id="maindiv">
.
.
.
</div>
```

For this code, for the first time after copydiv is appended, the clone that is added has id as "maindiv" and all the inner divs have the correct it.But when number is 2, the clone contains "changemain2" instead of maindiv.WHY is this?? Any remedy ????

Comment: `ID` has to be unique. That is probably why

Comment: Hi Rene..I am changing the IDs. "number" is being added.

Answer (score 4):

First, Id's have to unique in a DOM. On this, case where you are appending multiple sets, switch to class selectors.

Next, your variable `number` is local and redefined and reset to `1` on every `mousedown`

```
var copydiv = $('.maindiv').clone();  
var number = 1; // This was redefined and set as 1 on every `mousedown` 
                // So make it global

$("body").delegate(".imagediv","mousedown",function(event){       
    $(".maindiv").attr('class',"changedmain" + number);
    $(".imagediv").attr('class',"changedimage" + number );
    copydiv.insertAfter("#appendafter"); // You might have to change this too 
                                         // depending if this is repeated too
    number = number+1;
}
```

Also, It is preferable to delegate using a `.on()` function

```
$("body").on("mousedown", ".imagediv", function(event){       
    $(".maindiv").attr('class',"changedmain" + number);
    $(".imagediv").attr('class',"changedimage" + number );
    copydiv.insertAfter("#appendafter"); // You might have to change this too 
                                         // depending if this is repeated too
    number = number+1;
}
```

---

**Solution:**

The problem was with the method used. Elements cloned using `.clone()` will hold the reference, so instead of adding a new element it will keep updating previously referenced objects.

Here is the solution:

```
var number = 1; //Our Counter Script

function createDiv() {
    //Lets create a new div, 
             // I mean WHY CLONE AT the first place?? 
             // We are delegating events anyway :p

    $("<div />", {
        html : $('#maindiv').html(), // add the HTML of div we are trying to keep
             // ^ Better used cached 
             //   version is not updated regularly

        id : "maindiv-"+number       // add the generate id number 
    }).insertAfter("#appendafter");  // Now insert it
    number++;
}

$("body").on("mousedown", ".imagediv", function(event){
    createDiv(); //Delegating on all elements with `imagediv` class
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/SRcVH/)

Comment: I need to work only with ids. The ids are being changed carefully so that before the append the id of the existing DOM "maindiv" gets changed.

Comment: Also the cloning and append works fine for the first time when "number = 1". If it was a prob with ids it wouldnt have worked fine then too.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, Why do you need `id`? Selection is equally possible with classes.

Comment: I am running an editor on the div inside the maindiv.As for changing the existing id :$("#maindiv").attr('id', "changedmain" + number); is done before the copydiv.insertAfter("#appendafter");

Comment: I changed the position of number to be outside the mousedown:No help. Also somehow .on() is not working on firefox :(

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, You need jQuery 1.7 + to work `.on()` and I think I understand what you are trying. I will create a solution when I have time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using 1.8.2 lib ..still no help ..:)

Comment: Thank you so much ...Ill post some questions here if needed!

Comment: Hi...I actually didnt implement the solution you posted instead i simply moved my clone statement inside the delegate statement.So didnt accept your answer.Ill surely accept it in future if i happen to use it ..Thankx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your variable number, it has to be declared outside

Comment: Ouside???its already outside $("body").delegate(".imagediv","mousedown",function(event){

Comment: var number = 1; this line should go out of $("body").delegate()

Comment: Actually when inspecting the clone created the second time i get that its context has changed to "changedmain2" instead of being "maindiv" like for the first time.

Comment: Checked with that too ...No help

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty ........Well our dear function clone() basically maintains a reference.
I simply placed the statement

```
var copydiv = $('#maindiv').clone();
```

inside the  delegate statement:

```
  $("body").delegate("#imagediv", "mousedown", function(event) {
```

How it is working now..no idea ...but when on tight deadlines ...you never get to think too much ...Njoi!